# PHP: How to convert array to string

Tags: php, mysql, post

I've a PHP server with a *log* table in my MySQL database. When users connect to my server, I would like to store all the $_POST and $_GET variables into the log entry. The two variables is an array. Is there an easy way in PHP to convert these arrays to a string representation suitable for storing in my mySQL database?

As far as I know `implode()` is just for one-dimensional arrays. Maybe `json_encode()` would be a good way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode()` would work fine and be fairly compact, thus saving you space over some other more verbose alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `serialize()`/`unserialize()`

see [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I think `json_encode()` is more suitable in this case, as it is more compact.

Comment: @DennisMadsen -- Compactness aside, it is certainly more portable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `print_r($myTab)`.

Example (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.print-r.php):

```
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

Comment: You'd want to pass the second argument to `print_r()`, forcing return over output; `$string = print_r($array, true);`